# Why do we need two different conf files in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

We have two configuration files in Spark

1. spark-defaults.conf
2. spark-env.sh

What is the difference between these two files?
Can we both for a same spark application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **spark-env.sh**: sets all the system environment variables such as `SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV` `SPARK_HOME` etc. these environment variables are required for the spark installation to work properly. spark-env.sh is a shell script file
- **spark-defaults.conf**: This file sets all the spark configs such as 
  `spark.local.dir`, `spark.yarn.jars`. These config are necessary for your spark job to run properly. The below is from Spark's documentation.

> bin/spark-submit will also read configuration options from
>   conf/spark-defaults.conf, in which each line consists of a key and a
>   value separated by whitespace. For example:
>
> ```
>   spark.master            spark://5.6.7.8:7077
>   spark.executor.memory   4g
>   spark.eventLog.enabled  true
>   spark.serializer        org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer Any values specified as
> ```
>
> flags or in the properties file will be passed on to the application
>   and merged with those specified through SparkConf. Properties set
>   directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then flags passed
>   to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the
>   spark-defaults.conf file. A few configuration keys have been renamed
>   since earlier versions of Spark; in such cases, the older key names
>   are still accepted, but take lower precedence than any instance of the
>   newer key.

Comment: Ok Lets say I want to set a property which has to utilized by my all spark jobs. If that is the case then which property file  do I need to  use to set that property?

Comment: it should go under spark-defaults.conf